# Willie python irc bot - getting list of nicknames on a channel

Tags: python, bots, irc

I have a problem regarding the Willie (  http://willie.dftba.net/) Python irc bot.

I want to execute irc command "/names"

on the irc server, and then read the reply. With other words, I basically want to get the nicknames which are currently present on a irc channel. It should be some way to do this from within the Willie bot. If anyone has done this please reply.

What I've done so far:

1. Googled the problem
2. Went through all of the stuff (all of the wiki) on github
3. Went through (since i'm using it) the official Python documentation for Willie.
4. Written an email to the original creator of the Willie bot. (but no avail..)

If someone has any idea I would really appreciate it.

Thank you and best regards,

Satoshi

Answer (score 2):

The best way to get a list of names in a channel is [bot.privileges](http://willie.dftba.net/docs/#willie.bot.Willie.privileges). (`users = bot.privileges['#yourchannel']` will get you a dictionary of names to their privilege levels. You can iterate over just the nicks with `for nick in users: do_something(nick)`). That keeps the list up to date for you, so you don't need to deal with sending NAMES or parsing the reply.

If you do want to do parse the actual reply, Dan D. is right. You'll need to send `NAMES` in one function, and then have another that has `@rule('353')` to parse the reply.

Answer (score 1):

The closest I could find is how to send the NAMES command with `willie.write()` but it doesn't return the result of the command. So one would need to I think have a trigger on 353 RPL_NAMREPLY and 366 RPL_ENDOFNAMES that collects the results of the NAMES command.